# Java RSA encryption with public key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt a file with a public key I get from a certificate.

```
PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");        
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
```

throws an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not an RSA key!

I've tried :

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded());
PublicKey rsaPublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
```

but that throws `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException`: Invalid RSA public key

The constractor of `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey` expects 2 `BigInteger`s (probably the *modulus* and the *public exponent*).

Looking into `cert.getPublicKey()` reveals its a `DSAPublicKeyImpl`.

How can I convert it into an `RSAPublicKey` (or anything else) usable by `Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC")`?

Answer (score 3):

DSA keys can't be used for RSA encryption. DSA is only for signatures, and it uses different math requiring different key information.

Generate an RSA key instead, and use it with a library implementing a standard like CMS or PGP (BouncyCastle supports both). These use a random key for a symmetric cipher to encrypt the file, then encrypt that key with the public key of each recipient. There are many reasons this is a better approach.

Comment: Yes, I am actually trying to encrypt a symmetric key, I was just trying to simplify the problem. Still, I cant generate the recipient's keys, I have his certificate, how can I encrypt the key for him?

Comment: @user3116865 *DSA is for signatures* **only.** If the recipient wants to receive encrypted messages, he'll need to conduct Diffie-Hellman key exchange, signing his contribution to the exchange with his DSA certificate, or generate a new RSA key pair so that you can encrypt the key.